# VBScript Wildcard equivalent to T-SQL "%"

Tags: sql, vbscript, wildcard

I'm trying to basically to see if a file exists that has the current date in its filename.  In T-SQL when I want to search for something within a string, I just enclose it in "%" characters like this: %June 14 2012%

How do I do something like that in VBScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "*", since you're looking for files.

Comment: @KenWhite Point taken.  My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
Folder = "C:\" 

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set fold = fso.GetFolder(folder) 
For Each file in fold.Files 
    If Instr(file, "June") >0 Then
        Response.Write file.name & " got it in filename!"
    End if 
Next 
Set fold = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked, which was how to use a wildcard when searching for a file. Your answer won't work if, for instance, the search is for filenames starting with `J` and containing an `n`, as in `January`, `June`; a wildcard search on `J*n*` or `J?n*` would find them both. It also won't work if you're looking for files only for last year, as it would return all files with `June` in the name regardless of year.

Comment: This code might actually be useful for me even though it wasn't exactly what I asked for.  I'll try it out sometime.  Thanks.

Comment: @eek142 Instead of just checking for something containing in string you can use the RegExp object for more complex matches